# Bootstrap, small input with selection next to it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve something like this using bootstrap.  The input-group class hasn't been working for me.  Anyone else know how to do this??

[image]

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: This is already available as `input-group`. And yea, there's a dupe too! `:)` The working code can be found too. Check the snippet in the accepted answer. Styling the colours should be easier.